# Vagrant Virtualbox Openstack - or is there a better way?

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox, virtualization, openstack

## Current Steup

- Using a `Vagrant/Virtualbox` image for development
- `Vagrant` file and **php** code are both checked into a git repo
- When a new user joins the project they pull down the git repo and type `vagrant up`
- When we deploy to our "dev production" server we are on a CentOS 7 machine that has virtual box and vagrant and we just run the vagrant image

## Future Setup

We are moving towards an OpenStack "cloud" and are wondering how to best integrate this current setup into the workflow

As I understand it OpenStack allows you to create individual VMs - which sounds cool because on one hand we could then launch our VM's, but the problem is we are taking advantage of Vagrant/Virtual Box's "mapping" functionality so that we are mounting `/var/www/html` to a `/html` directory in the folder we run vagrant out of.  I assume this is not possible with OpenStack - and was wondering whether there is a specified best practice for how to handle this situation.

## Approach

The only approach i can think of is to:

- Install a VM on OpenStack that runs Centos7 and then inside that VM run Vagrant/VirtualBox (this seems bonkers)

But then we have VM inside a VM inside a VM and that just doesn't seem efficient.

Is there a tool - or guide - or guidance how to work with both a local vagrant image and the cloud?  It seems like there may not be as easy a mapping as I initially though.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to keep using vagrant, presumably using https://github.com/ggiamarchi/vagrant-openstack-provider or similar?  With that assumption, the way to do this which is probably the smallest iteration from your current setup is just to use an `rsync` synced folder - see https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/rsync.html. You should be able to something like this:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "html/", "/var/www/html", type: 'rsync'
```

Check the rest of that rsync page though -- depending on your ssh user, you might need to use the `--rsync-path` option.

NB - you don't mention whether you vagrant host is running windows or linux etc. If you're on windows then I tend to use cygwin, though I expect you can otherwise find some rsync.exe to use.

If you can free yourself from the vagrant pre-requisite then there are many solutions, but the above should be a quick win from where you are now.

Comment: My vagrant locally runs on mac - and for production we are hoping to be running on centos/openstack - the nice thing about vagrant is we can check the provisioning stuff into our repo